# Extract elements from the array in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that is shown below

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CustomerNo|recommendations                                                                     |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|76        |[{1, 0.89554673}, {5, 0.85469896}, {2, 0.84503603}, {0, 0.80415034}, {6, 0.6815199}]|
|336       |[{1, 1.0019907}, {5, 0.9514036}, {4, 0.83544296}, {0, 0.76875824}, {7, 0.7413829}]  |
|654       |[{5, 1.0243652}, {1, 0.9433953}, {6, 0.81832266}, {7, 0.69486576}, {8, 0.6834659}]  |
```

schema:

```
root
 |-- CustomerNo: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- category: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

I have to extract the key from each list from each row. For example, the output table should be like

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CustomerNo|recommendations                                                                     |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|76        |[1,5,2,0,6]                                                                         |
|336       |[1,5,4,0,7]                                                                         |
|654       |[5,1,6,7,8]                                                                         |
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: What type of elements is in the `recommendations` column?

Comment: Please print schema, that determines potential approach

Comment: @wwnde added the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CustomerNo|recommendations                                                                     |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|76        |[{1, 0.89554673}, {5, 0.85469896}, {2, 0.84503603}, {0, 0.80415034}, {6, 0.6815199}]|
|336       |[{1, 1.0019907}, {5, 0.9514036}, {4, 0.83544296}, {0, 0.76875824}, {7, 0.7413829}]  |
|654       |[{5, 1.0243652}, {1, 0.9433953}, {6, 0.81832266}, {7, 0.69486576}, {8, 0.6834659}]  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.select('CustomerNo',col('recommendations.category').alias("recommendations")).show()


+----------+---------------+
|CustomerNo|recommendations|
+----------+---------------+
|        76|[1, 5, 2, 0, 6]|
|       336|[1, 5, 4, 0, 7]|
|       654|[5, 1, 6, 7, 8]|
+----------+---------------+
```